# Javascript - Convert EST timezone to EDT timezone based on our present timzone

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date, datetime, timezone

I have a timespan section which has a start date and an end date.

What I want to achieve is if my start date is in EST and my end date falls in EDT, then I would want to change my start date to EDT.

(From the first Sunday of November until the second Sunday of March, follow EST otherwise EDT)

Let's say my Start Date is :

```
new Date('1/10/2023').toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York",timeZoneName: 'short'});
```

Output: `1/10/2023, 12:00:00 AM EST`

and my End Date is :

```
new Date('3/20/2023').toLocaleString("en-US", {timeZone: "America/New_York",timeZoneName: 'short'});
```

Output: `3/20/2023, 12:00:00 AM EDT`

I would want my Start Date output as :
`1/10/2023, 01:00:00 AM EDT` instead of `1/10/2023, 12:00:00 AM EST`

Is there any graceful way in Javascript through which I can achieve this ?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve.  `America/New_York` already accounts for both EST and EDT, depending on which is in effect for the date being converted.  But also, your input string is not in the required format, and even if it was it would be parsed as midnight in your local time zone, not in NY.  Even thin, it's still not clear why you think it should be `01:00` instead of `00:00`.

Comment: Also, until [Temporal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/) is widely available, you might want to consider using a library such as [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/), [dayJS](https://day.js.org/), or [date-fns](https://date-fns.org/).

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint What I want is, if EDT is in effect as of now, I want my start date which was in EST to be converted into EDT.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  Daylight saving time applies to specific dates and times. One doesn't apply DST to a date/time that was not in DST.  In other words, it doesn't matter what is in effect as of _now_, it matters only what was in affect as of _then_.